# Enable dark-mode in GTK2

Tags: theme, gtk3, gtk2, dark-mode

So I am using Arc as my GTK theme, and applied it like this

```
[Settings]
gtk-icon-theme-main=Arc
gtk-theme-name=Arc
gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme=true
```

in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`

To enable it for GTK2, I did this:

```
gtk-theme-name="Arc"
gtk-icon-theme-name="Arc"
gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme="true"
```

in `~/.gtkrc-2.0`. However, gimp and some other applications (I assume they are GTK2) are light.. Others have correctly been given the Arc Dark theme and the icon-theme as well..

How do I enable the dark-mode for GTK2?

Comment: Solved it by adding Arc-Dark and "Arc-Dark" on gtk-theme-name for both Gtk2 and Gtk3..

Comment: Consider to expand the comment into a proper answer. Yes, you can [answer your own question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 3):

Using the name `Arc-Dark` for both GTK2 and GTK3 solves the issue.

GTK3:

```
[Settings]
gtk-icon-theme-main=Arc-Dark
gtk-theme-name=Arc-Dark
```

GTK2:

```
gtk-theme-name="Arc-Dark"
gtk-icon-theme-name="Arc-Dark"
```